# Weighting the examples in AdaBoost: Distributions, gradients, and the equation

Tags: boosting, loss-functions, adaboost

When creating a new, $j$th learner using AdaBoost, the model for defining the weight of an example is:
$$w_{j}^i = e^{-y_ih_{j-1}^i}$$
These weights are created in order that the new learner will focus on previously misclassified examples.

How does multiplying the actual and expected outputs substitute for a loss function? Would something like $e^{\epsilon_i}$($\epsilon_i = y_i - h^i_{j}$) be more appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Actually, it is natural to consider the product between predicted and expected label. It comes from the way that AdaBoost was designed.*

---

Indeed, AdaBoost is an algorithm that aims at minimizing the *exponential loss*, which is defined as :
$$\mathcal{l}_{exp}(h)=\mathbb{E}[\exp(-Yh(X))] $$
The question you might ask now is why it is defined this way. It comes from the convexification of the *misclassification loss*. Indeed, misclassification loss is classically defined as follows (in the case of binary classification with labels +1 and -1):
$$\mathcal{l}(h)= \mathbb{P}(h(X) \neq Y) = \mathbb{P}(Yh(X) < 0) =  \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{h(X)Y < 0}] $$
This definition is inconvenient to optimize, and we prefer considering convexified versions of the loss, defined as follows:

$$ \mathcal{l}_{\phi}(h) = \mathbb{E}[\phi(Yh(X))] $$

with $\phi$ non-increasing, convex, $\phi(0) = 1$. This way we have:
$$ \mathcal{l}(h) \leq\mathcal{l}_{\phi}(h) $$
and it can be shown that optimizing both versions leads to the same classifier.

AdaBoost has been designed to minimize the convexified loss with $\phi(x) = \exp(-x)$.

---

For more details, you can refer to the first sections of the chapter **Boosting and Additive Trees** from the book  *The Elements of Statistical Learning*. It is very well explained there.

Comment: Thank you. What about if my output is continous?